# Cordova Plugin for SQL on Windows 10 (UWP)

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, web-sql, windows-10-universal

I'm developing a Cordova application but I need a Web SQL driver to store my data. Basically I want to be using the database built in the browser (Web SQL) and I've managed to get it to work for IOS and Android. Now I want to test it on Windows 10 (UWP), but I keep bumping into problems.

I've added this plugin in Visual Studio for the Windows 10 version: 
`Web SQL Plugin: cordova-plugin-websql`

On the npm website ([Link here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-websql#websql-plugin-for-apache-cordova)) it says the following: 
`Support of Windows 8.0, Windows 8.1, Windows Phone 8.0 and Windows Phone 8.1.`

This could possibly be the reason why my app keeps crashing.

**TL;DR**: Is there a (solid) SQL plugin for cordova that supports Windows 10 (UWP) applications?

Answer (score 0):

Been there done that, Cordova WP SQLite plugin asks for a lot of pain. But i will advise you to take a loot at Channel9 tutorial on this WebSQL plugin for Cordova here

https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Interoperability/New-Cross-Platform-Cordova-plugin-by-MS-Open-Tech-WebSQL

This will help you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a (solid) SQL plugin for cordova that supports Windows 10 (UWP) applications?

Yes, the cordova-sqlite-ext supports Windows10(UWP).

> It is a Cordova/PhoneGap plugin to open and use sqlite databases on Android/iOS/Windows 10 (UWP) with REGEXP (Android/iOS) and pre-populated databases (Android/iOS/Windows)

You can add this plugin in Visual Studio by:

open config.xml designer → click Plugins tag → Custom → Git → enter Git repository location → add Plugin.